# Textures for 3DS model into Rajawali

Tags: java, android, rajawali

I'm very new to Android development and I have a project to do for the school.

I decided to use the Rajawali Framework and I tried to import a 3DS Max model.
This is the code I use :

```
Loader3DSMax parser = new Loader3DSMax(this, R.raw.hst_3ds);
hubble = parser.parse().getParsedObject();
scene.addChild(hubble);
```

The model is displayed, but with no materials.
I have no errors.

In a first time, I thought that my BMP textures weren't supported because in the [Obj importation tutorial](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-17-Importing-.Obj-Files) I can read :

> If it still throws errors check if there are any funny characters or unsupported texture formats (like bmp).

So I converted my textures to JPG and put a copy into drawable-nodpi.
Also, my textures are coming from the NASA and they already use power of two image resolutions.

But it still doesn't works. I tried some variations (eg. without file extension).

Comment: It seems you have to convert your model into an `obj` and a `mtl` files. `my textures are coming from the NASA` I fear these image are way too big (very high res) and will cause OOMs.

Comment: I will try that. Do you have a good converter, on the Web or for Linux?

Comment: Blender. http://www.blender.org/

Comment: I converted the object to OBJ and this is alot better but I still do not have textures.
But now the model reacts to light and the different parts of the HST are in different colors. See http://i.imgur.com/J1qaCrz.png 

No problem for the textures, the NASA made a collection of small, low-poly models of the space exploration. You can find it here : http://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/models
The textures are not exceeding 2048px.